# react facebook comment in iphone 5,6 error format css

Tags: reactjs

I am using facebook comment and the error is like the picture.

```
const FacebookComment: React.FC<Props> = ({ title }) => {
      const isMobile = ...
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
      const [dataHref, setDataHref] = useState('');
      const rootRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
      const route = useRouter();
      useEffect(() => {...
      }, [route]);
    
      useEffect(() => {...
        };
        try {
          window.FB?.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', handleRendered);
          return () => window.FB?.Event.unsubscribe('xfbml.render', handleRendered);
        } catch (e) {
          // Ignore error
        }
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
      }, [dataHref]);
    
      return (
        <div ref={rootRef} className={isMobile ? css.rootMobile : css.rootDesktop} >
          
          {dataHref && <div className="fb-comments" data-href={dataHref} data-width="100%" data-numposts="5" />}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default FacebookComment;
```

iphone 5,6
[image]

iphone x

[image]

problem: I am using code like above but on iphone 6 and iphone x display differently. I want to fix error on iphone 6.
hope some one can help me!!!